# Newcommand + Stepcounter

Tags: sectioning, counters

I'm trying to come up with a command which should increase a counter and return a string including the current value of the counter.

Have a look at the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\mystepFAILS}{\stepcounter{mycounter}foo\themycounter}
\newcommand{\mystepWORKS}{foo\themycounter}

\begin{document}

\section{\mystepFAILS}

\section{\mystepWORKS}

\end{document}
```

Why does the command with `\mystepFAILS` throw an error? What is so special about `\stepcounter`? Any ideas?

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\mystepFAILS}{\stepcounter{mycounter}foo\themycounter}` should work; or, alternatively, `\section{\protect\mystepFAILS}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to directly use `\stepcounter` in a section title, because section titles are massaged several times. Even if it worked you'd end up with problems when the table of contents is typeset, because the counter would be stepped at an inappropriate time.

Consider this input:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\mystep}{\protect\stepcounter{mycounter}foo\themycounter}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\mystep}


\end{document}
```

This will have “foo1” in the table of contents and “foo2” in the document at the second LaTeX run and ”foo2” in both places at the subsequent runs.

With section in the headings (`\pagestyle{headings}`), it would be even worse, because the counter would be stepped at each page where the heading appears.

If you don't plan to have a table of contents, then `\protect` will suffice. But the best is to define a new command:

```
\newcommand{\step}{\stepcounter{mycounter}\section{foo\themycounter}}
```

and use `\step` at the required spot

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\step}{\stepcounter{mycounter}\section{foo\themycounter}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\step


\end{document}
```

Another, complicated, strategy would be to say

```
\section[foo\themycounter]{\stepcounter{mycounter}foo\themycounter}
```

Comment: Ah now I get it ;-) Thanks for your detailed explanations! I will go with the second idea, since it seems to be more safe.