# Update counter in label for newcommand

Tags: macros, ref

I am trying to create a new section that automatically updates the counter with relevant label.

[newcommand-stepcounter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150682/newcommand-stepcounter) sort of does what I am trying to do , but not quite.

When I use the code below, the counters on the sections headed "Eq" are updated as I'd like, but if I try to `\label` them then the section number is used rather than the counter on the new command.

How can I use the relevant counter when using `label` please.

```
\documentclass{report}    
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\step}{\stepcounter{mycounter}\subsubsection*{Eq \themycounter}}   

\begin{document}

\section{}
\subsection{}
\step\label{eq:one}

\section{}
\subsection{}
\step

As seen in Eq~\ref{eq:one}

\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Comment: I think that if you replace `\stepcounter` by `\refstepcounter` it'll work...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik ; that works thank you. If you would like to add it as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: The answer, as you requested :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to change `\stepcounter` to `\refstepcounter`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\step}{\refstepcounter{mycounter}\subsubsection*{Eq \themycounter}}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\subsection{}
\step\label{eq:one}

\section{}
\subsection{}
\step

As seen in Eq~\ref{eq:one}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

`\stepcounter` just adds `1` to the counter but `\refstepcounter` makes the `\@currentlabel` be that counter:

```
\def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
       {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
```

so when you are using `\label`s, `\stepcounter` alone isn't enough because LaTeX doesn't know that the counter is a label.

Comment: Dear Phelype; how could I tweak this to increment letters instead of numerics please. I thought something like `\newcommand{\step}{\refstepcounter{mycounter} (\alph{\themycounter})}` would work but with no joy. Thanks

Comment: This seems to work `\newcounter{mycounter};
\renewcommand{\themycounter}{(\alph{mycounter})};
\newcommand{\step}{\refstepcounter{mycounter} \themycounter}`

Comment: @user20650 Yes, if you want to change how a counter `<counter>` _looks_ you redefine the command `\the<counter>`. Your first approach didn't work because the argument to `\alph` (and `\roman` and `\arabic`) are counter _names_ (so `<counter>`, not `\the<counter>`).

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. I just chucked a few things a it till one stuck -- very robust code.