# How to add custom numbering to sections or subsections?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters

I would like to have subsections with "parts" like the following code but possibly managed automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem}
\subsection{Ipsum part 1: Foo}
\subsection{Ipsum part 2: Bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have *all* your `\subsection`s having this formatting?

Comment: Very related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21300/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219043/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150682/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335035/35864